# Генерация 15-значного числа. Java

Tags: java, случайные-числа, генераторы

Сгенерировать 15-значное число.

Comment: BigInteger или строку? Берёте 14 любых цифр, добавляете их к одной от 1 до 9 - получаете 15 значное число.

Comment: @vp_arth, так в long же влезает

Comment: действительно, что-то я того

Answer (score 1):

Мой колхозный вариант :) 
Правда есть значения которые он точно не сгенерит, по понятным причинам.

```
public class Random15 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr4 = new int[15];
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
        arr4[i] = ((int) (Math.random() * 10));
        System.out.print(arr4[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

long v = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(100000000000000L, 1000000000000000L);
```

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong-long-long-)